# Accessing dynamically to a Kotlin class property

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to set dynamically a backgroundColor to a text view in a RecyleView, and thus not all my item will have the same background color for their tag.

This is the pseudo code I'd like to use :

```
val name = item.type.toLowerCase()
color = ContextCompat(item.context, R.color[name])
```

But this syntax does not seem to work in Kotlin, and I really have no idea how to fetch the color value from the resource depending on the type of the item.

I also tried this:

```
val lowerType = pokemon.type.toLowerCase()
val id = holder.context.resources.getIdentifier(lowerType, "id", holder.context.packageName)
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.context, id)
```

But this crashes too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to access the resources in a dynamic way, you will lose compile-time safety and code completion. In your case, you could create a `Map` that associates every view type to the resource you want (i.e. *color*).

**Example**

```
/* colors.xml */
<color name="color_view_1">#AA000000</color>
<color name="color_view_2">#AB000000</color>
<color name="color_view_3">#AC000000</color>
<color name="color_view_4">#AD000000</color>
<color name="color_view_default">#AE000000</color>

/* Adapter */
enum class ViewType {
    TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3
}

val colors = mapOf(
    ViewType.TYPE1 to R.color.color_view_1,
    ViewType.TYPE2 to R.color.color_view_2,
    ViewType.TYPE3 to R.color.color_view_3
)

/* onBindViewHolder */
val color = colors[viewType] ?: R.color.color_view_default
```

Comment: Oh sorry, what I meant by type is actually a string. In this case these are Pokemons so leaf, fire, water etc ...

Comment: @NeilRichter, It's a good opportunity to use an `enum` or `seal class` for that instead of a raw `String`, if not just change the keys of the `Map` to `String`

Comment: @NeilRichter i.e. `val colors = mapOf(
        "leaf" to R.color.color_view_1,
        "fire" to R.color.color_view_2,
        "water" to R.color.color_view_3,
        "earth" to R.color.color_view_4
    )`

Answer (score 0):

You should set `"color"` and not `"id"` for `getIdentifier()`'s 2nd argument:

```
val id = holder.context.resources.getIdentifier(lowerType, "color", holder.context.packageName)
```